# 2012 questions clean up

Tags: support, deleted-questions

As part of cleaning up the site, I'm deleting multiple closed and abandoned questions from 2011 where I think they have no historical significance.

Please review the following list, if there is any question that I've deleted by mistake, point it out in an answer.

**Notes**

- "it's salvageable/can be fixed" is not a good reason to not delete at this point. These questions have been abandoned for a long time. If you think it's salvageable, *fix it by editing first* and then add an answer.
- "migrate this" is also not a good reason -- we simply don't migrate old, possibly answered, closed questions to other sites. *However*, if you think a post would be a great question elsewhere ...ask it again on the new site!
- only high-rep users and owners will be able to see the posts.

**Deleted questions**

- [Is it rational to avoid touching doorknobs, elevator buttons and other public surfaces?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/5789/96)
- [Does shifting an Automatic Transmission vehicle into neutral at red lights save fuel?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/14156/96)
- [is jon skeet just one person?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/14119/96)
- [Was Vincent Van Gogh colour blind?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/13984/96)
- [VASIMR - Earth to Mars in 39 days?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/13821/96)
- [Is it possible to 'use up' your vocal chords from singing in a band?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/10834/96)
- [Did Apple ever invent any technology on its own?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/10661/96)
- [Is the best way to fall asleep by trying to stay awake?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/10423/96)
- [Can the radioactive material on the Curiosity rover create risk to present or future life on Mars?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/10422/96)
- [Are Genetic Algorithms evidence to support evolution?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/9820/96)
- [Would standing next to a lava flow kill you from the heat/gasses even if you did not touch it?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/9686/96)
- [Is this an image of the Milky Way galaxy?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/9622/96)
- [Where does Lucky Strike cigarettes' name come from?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/9542/96)
- [Will opening a car door at high speed cause a flip?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/9532/96)
- [Is this arrangement of coins possible?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/9480/96)
- [Can turbines on the front of cars ever pay off?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/9478/96)
- [Were there ever any photos/pictures of Hitler's bunker published by Allied armies?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/9401/96)
- [Does eating pizza decrease 'energy'?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/9000/96)
- [Are online petitions making any effect at all?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/8857/96)
- [Does the name of Easter derive from a goddess called Eostre?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/8789/96)
- [Is working more than 40 hours a week pointless?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/8578/96)
- [Is there a logical explanation for coulrophobia (fear of clowns)?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/8565/96)
- [Is "orthomolecular medicine" a hoax similar to homeopathy?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/8459/96)
- [Is there a STEM worker shortage?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/8446/96)
- [Does "Chi" exist?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/8312/96)
- [Correlation/relationship between human magnetic field and body temperature](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/8416/96)
- [Are there weather conditions on Earth where winds could 'blow someone over'?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/8194/96)
- [Do biologists distinguish between fruits and vegetables?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/8149/96)
- [Was Atlantis a real place or civilization?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/7781/96)
- [What are the origins of the number 13 being unlucky?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/7564/96)
- [Does the existence of private education lower the standard of education in a country overall?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/7412/96)

Comment: Secondo me, invece, “Was Vincent Van Gogh colour blind?” è una domanda interessante e, in quanto tale, meritevole di essere lasciata lì, after all it got nine upvotes, no?